# Show method description in tooltip/popup in monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop, unity-game-engine

How can I display the tooltip/popup or whatever the thing on the right is to show the method documentation. The bare minimum it has locally.

I'm talking about the yellow-ish section here: http://puu.sh/snnA7/0d024d8937.png

Ctrl + ' is a very, very, very slow and dumb way of checking method descriptions.

After I've written a method, I'd like to move my cursor on it and press something like Ctrl + Space for instance and have it display that popup and let me check other methods or at least see the short description for it or SOMETHING !! Anything!! Same goes for field values.

Please tell me there IS a way of doing this. It's driving me crazy !

**EDIT**
In Visual Studio it's called "Quick Info"

Answer (score 0):

In MonoDevelop you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (while the cursor is inside the braces) to show the overloads and documentation of the specific method.